# IsSelected property of WPF TabItem

Tags: wpf, tabitem

I have the following code:

```
<TabItem Name="tabItemGeneral">
    <TabItem.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="tabGeneralImg" Property="Source" Value="Image/tabGeneralActive.png"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </TabItem.Triggers>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-3,0,0">
            <Image Name="tabGeneralImg" Source="Images/tabGeneral.png" Width="11" Height="11"></Image>
            <Label Name="tabGeneralLbl" Content="General"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <Grid>
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

but I get 
Error   1   'IsSelected' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.   C:\MyNET\bluetooth\iLockWPF\iLock\iLock\MainWindow.xaml 63  60  iLock

during compilation. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As CodeNaked said, it is unable to use property triggers directly on elements. You should use HeaderTemplate instead.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tabItemGeneralHeaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        Margin="0,-3,0,0">
                <Image Name="tabGeneralImg" 
                       Source="Image/tabGeneralActive.png" 
                       Width="11" 
                       Height="11"/>
                <Label Name="tabGeneralLbl" 
                       Content="General"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected
                                ,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="tabGeneralImg" 
                            Property="Source" 
                            Value="Images/tabGeneral.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Name="tabItemGeneral" 
             HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource tabItemGeneralHeaderTemplate}">
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 4):

The [TabItem.Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers.aspx) collection is inherited from FrameworkElement and can only contain [EventTriggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx). What you have is not valid.

Triggers, MultiTriggers, DataTriggers, and MultiDataTriggers can only be used in the [Style.Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers.aspx), [ControlTemplate.Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.triggers.aspx), or [DataTemplate.Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.triggers.aspx) collections.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use TabItem.IsSelected?

```
<Trigger Property="TabItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
  <Setter TargetName="tabGeneralImg" Property="Source" Value="Image/tabGeneralActive.png">
  </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: it says that "'Source' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name. " right now