# Custom TabItem header with text and image - not sure how to proceeed

Tags: wpf, image, header, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a TabControl in my XAML which is just an empty control as the TabItems are dynamically generated at runtime.

My problem is I want to have the tab title and an image (a "settings" image) in the Header but I'm not sure how to go about this.  As I said,  I'm generating the TabItems on the fly so how and where would  a template to do this fit in and where would I put it etc?  Would a TabItem header template apply to TabItem controls created dynamically?  (I am assuming/hoping so!)

I've googled and searched around here but no-one quite seems to be doing what I'm doing... just wondering if someone could give me some guidance.

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid" Background="#333333" ShowGridLines="False" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" ToolTip="Settings">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="RoboNews" Foreground="SkyBlue" FontSize="32" Padding="5"/>
        <Button Name="btnSettings" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#333333" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                Click="btnSettings_Click" ToolTip="Click for menu">
            <!--<Image Source="Images/Settings48x48.png"/>-->
            <Image Source="/Images/MenuOpen.png" Width="36" />
        </Button>

    </Grid>

    <TabControl Name="tabCategories" Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" SelectionChanged="tabCategories_SelectionChanged">  

    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You want the tab title and an image for each TabItem you have created?

Comment: stukselbax, yes that's correct... just not sure how to create the template or where to put it or if the dynamically created TabItem will pick it up and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a UserControl for your header

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" x:Class="TabControlHeader.TabItemHeader"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Grid >
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

With ideally DPs defined in its ViewModel, but for the time being, in code behind:

```
public string ImageSource
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(TabItemHeader));



public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TabItemHeader));
```

Then while creating your TabItem you need to set its HeaderTemplate:

```
TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
tabItem.Height = 100;
tabItem.Width = 50;
var header = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TabItemHeader));
header.SetValue(TabItemHeader.TextProperty, "This is Text");
header.SetValue(TabItemHeader.ImageSourceProperty, "This is Image uri");
header.SetValue(TabItemHeader.HeightProperty, (double)50);
header.SetValue(TabItemHeader.WidthProperty, (double)50);


tabItem.HeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = header };            
tabCategories.Items.Add(tabItem);
```

Comment: Hey gaurawerma, thanks you so much for that - I hadn't thought about doing it with DP's so your solution looks great!  I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked really well - just need to make some cosmetic changes and add an event handler for the image and I'm in business! This was also a lot simpler than I thought it would be - I really need to up my knowledge of DP's.  Many thanks for the answer!

Comment: One more question - in the code behind of my Main window, when the entire tab is selected I need to get the instance of the TabItemHeader control so I can change the visibility of the image (which is wrapped in a Button tag) but I'm not sure how to cast it back to an type of TabItemHeader so I can sat btnSettings.Visibility = Visibility.Visible.  (The button starts out with Visibility = Hidden).  
I can see that it's the VisualTree of the HeaderTemplate but I can't work out how to cast it from a FrameworkElementFactory to an instance of TabItemHeader control.... any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I should first suggest you to use DataTemplate instead of creating a user control for HeaderTemplate as I did. The solution I provided is on the fly and is not upto the mark. You should create a DataTemplate in your style resources and then assign the same to the tabitem HeaderTemplate on the fly. Now coming back to your question,  what I can understand is you need to bind the visibility of the Button inside your headertemplate to the IsSelected property of your tabItem. You can achieve this using DataTrigger. For reference you can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/6014444/840039

Comment: Hey thanks again - I realised today this wasn't the way to do it as no matter what I tried the VisualTree got reset at each tab change so all the buttons were always either visible or invisible.  Will check out your link... really appreciate the help though.  :-)